# SSL cert for kubernetes Ingress for custom domain hosted by google domain

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have purchased a domain name from google domains.

I setup a project with GCLOUD Kubernetes using Ingress.

Documentation for ingress [Ingress Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce) says to enter 
key here:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: testsecret
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
data:
  tls.crt: base64 encoded cert
  tls.key: base64 encoded key
```

I found doc for how to configure and get SSL cert for app engine. [app engine custom domains](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains).

I'm guessing that app engine SSL config has nothing to do with kubernetes ingress.

Would like to know how to get and maintain ssl cert for my ingress.

Comment: So all you want is a cert, not how to apply it?

Answer (score 1):

Ingress can be secured with the [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) having TLS private key and the certificate. Then can provide reference to the secret in the ingress. Refer to this [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/README.md#frontend-https) for more information.

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/tls) is the example for the TLS Ingress rule to use SSL in NGINX along with information on storing SSL certificate in a secret.

### Example:

Create secret:

```
kubectl create secret tls foo-secret --key /tmp/tls.key --cert /tmp/tls.crt
```

Reference secret in the ingress:

```
      spec:
      tls:
      - hosts:
      foo.bar.com
      secretName: foo-secret
```

You may also wants to check these links/documentation, which can help you.

[Link 1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-secret-tls-em-)
[Link 2](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/gce/examples/https)
[Link 3](https://runnable.com/blog/how-to-use-lets-encrypt-on-kubernetes)

Comment: Thank you. What about the cert themselves. Google app appears to offer auto update of certs, like wise so does "lets encrypt".  Any what to automate the cert refresh when using ingress ?

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/70801227) in place for automated certificate management. You can "star" [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/70801227) feature request to show your interest in this feature.

Comment: I cant find documentation on the timestamp "last_updated" in your "Link 3". Does anyone know what this does?

Comment: @grabbag I could not find any documentation on "last_updated" label as well. However, as per the comment describing the label 'last_update' in ingress.yaml file, it is 'Timestamp used in order to force reload of the secret'. It should work just using the 'kubectl apply -f ingress_file.yaml' as well.